# Why child div modification change all others childs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this html structure :

```
  <div id="guide_rubric" class="col-md-2 anti-padding">
    <div id="rubric_1" class="col-md-12 anti-padding rubric-text rubric-focus-other"><span onclick="rubric_click(5)" class="span-rubric">Climat et météo</span></div>
    <div id="rubric_2" class="col-md-12 anti-padding rubric-text rubric-focus-other"><span onclick="rubric_click(5)" class="span-rubric">Climat et météo</span></div>
    <div id="rubric_3" class="col-md-12 anti-padding rubric-text rubric-focus-other"><span onclick="rubric_click(5)" class="span-rubric">Climat et météo</span></div>
    <div class="planificationDescription">
      <p>some text</p>
    </div>
    <button id="guideTripButton" onclick="location.href='/apps/'" class="btn">C'est parti !</button>
  </div>
```

But when I add some style to the class planificationDescription, it changes the style of all guide_rubric.

For exemple if i add a background color, all other divs change.

I add the divs like this :

```
<div id="rubric_1" class="col-md-12 anti-padding rubric-text rubric-focus-other"><span onclick="rubric_click(5)" class="span-rubric">Climat et météo</span></div>
```

dynamically.

Website : https://dimitri-dev.facilitatrip.fr/visiter/guide-touristique/Asie/Vietnam/3

It's the menu on the left.

Comment: You'll need to put an [mcve] in the question using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) so it's runnable, demonstrating the problem. Adding a style to that class shouldn't have that effect.

Comment: Can you post the CSS you're trying to apply?

Comment: Can you include your styles in the question? Styles for that class should not affect other divs.

Comment: Can you explain the problem? Currently its really not clear. Your website works and I don't see how anything there changes the background-color of all the dives.

Comment: @Dekel try to add a background color to the class planificationDescription, then the color of the whole menu will change, when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to clear floting of other elements.
Pls add `clear:both;` to `planificationDescription`class.

```
.planificationDescription{
     clear:both;
     background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As i can see in your website: https://dimitri-dev.facilitatrip.fr/visiter/guide-touristique/Asie/Vietnam/3

All you "rubric" id elements have class "col-xs-12" class, which gives them float property.

Element with id "planificationDescription" has no such class which is not a floated element, hence it is taking the whole height of the parent height.

Solution:

1:

```
#planificationDescription {
  float: left;
}
```

2:

```
<div class="clearfix">
  <div id="rubric_1" class="col-md-12 anti-padding rubric-text rubric-focus-other"><span onclick="rubric_click(5)" class="span-rubric">Climat et météo</span></div>
   <div id="rubric_2" class="col-md-12 anti-padding rubric-text rubric-focus-other"><span onclick="rubric_click(5)" class="span-rubric">Climat et météo</span></div>
   <div id="rubric_3" class="col-md-12 anti-padding rubric-text rubric-focus-other"><span onclick="rubric_click(5)" class="span-rubric">Climat et météo</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="planificationDescription">
      <p>some text</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, the first solution worked fine, and I understand better now.

Comment: I would actually go with `clear: left` and not `float: left`

Comment: It looks more relevant to use `clear: left;` than making the element a floating one

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding background color to  class="planificationDescription" then make sure this class has correct css with width/height or you can give width and height in background property of css

Answer (score -1):

**This is tested!!!**

```
<!--just to be specific and sure-->
<!--Just add another class to the div like-->
<div class="planificationDescription data_at1"><p>some text</p></div>

<!--And in css you would target that like-->
<style>
    div.planificationDescription.data_at1{
        /*style required!!!*/
    }
</style>



<!--Another alternative is to add a unique attr like below-->
<div class="planificationDescription" about="data_at1"><p>some text</p></div>
<!--And in css you would target that like-->
<style>
    div.planificationDescription[about=data_at1]{
        /*style required!!!*/
    }
</style>
```